# Add guassian noise to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `a` with size `n*2`, I want to add a guassian noise to each value `a[i,j]` with `mean= a[i,j]` and `standard deviation = 0.2* a[i,j]` to each number in the array.  Could you please help me with that?

Here is a sample of array:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(10,2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html), the `np.random.normal` function takes an array-like for both the mean and stdev arguments, so

```py
x = np.random.rand(10, 2)
noise = np.random.normal(x, 0.2*x)

x + noise
```

However, I don't quite follow your reasoning behind using each value in the array as the mean... if you want to add noise to data, why not use `loc=0`? That would then add +/- a tiny bit of Gaussian distributed noise to each of the values without heavily skewing each value.

For instance, if `x[i,j] == 6`, and you added noise centered on `~G(6, 1.2)`, then `x[i, j]` would be as large as 12 *on average*, which isn't so much adding noise as it is fundamentally changing the data.

Here, taking `6` to be the value at some given coordinate `x[i, j]`,

```py
In [12]: 6 + np.random.normal(6, 0.2*6)
Out[12]: 13.812965429428406
```

Your `6` turned into `13.81` -- is this your intention?

Depending on each of the distributions, you'd could be *consistently shifting all your data* in the positive direction, which is almost certainly not what you intend. If you're simply trying to add jitter to your data, you should use `loc=0`.